# React Native project dont run on a android emulator (android studio)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have made android emulator and other things properly but nothing really works for me. It says,
**Couldn't start project on Android: The system cannot find the path specified**
I am using windows 10 as operating system.

[image: Please see the attached image here]

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.
check your `ANDROID_HOME` variable in advance system setting.
It must point to your SDK: `C:\Users\$USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Comment: there's no sdk there. The path is C:\Android\android-sdk/emulator/emulator